# specify a floating point range using regular expression

Tags: regex, mod-security

I need an regular expression to check whether a particular argument is in a floating point range.For ex i want the Param only in the range 0.01 to 999.9 . I have configured the below rule ,but it fails to work .

```
SecRule ARGS:Param "![0.01-999.9]" "deny,id:2200"
```

If the value of `param` is say 1000 it gets rejected which is correct , if the value of `Param` is 0 then its being accepted which should not be the case .Please let me know the exact way of configuring the regular expression for the same.

Comment: Regexs weren't designed to solve such problems, unfortunately!

Comment: BTW, `1-9` is interpreted as a character class.  `.` is interpreted as a single character.  So it's not tough to figure why something is working.

Comment: are you sure there is no better way than with regexes?

Comment: mod_security does pattern matching with regexes , and the action is performed after matching the regex .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this sounds like a buisness logic rule - something that should be done in the server logic, not by mod_security, but anyways:

Floating point numbers in the range `[0..999.9]` are numbers that

- start with an optional sequence of zeroes (you may or may not allow that)
- followed by at most three digits, first of which is not zero
- optionally followed by a dot and nothing but digits (you may require there be at least one digit the last digit to be nonzero)
- except numbers that start with `999.9` and said optional zeroes
- except `999.9` itself is allowed (if the range is inclusive from the right)

the least restrictive variant, compiled into a regex:

```
^0*(?:(?!999\.9\d*$)\d{0,3}(?:\.\d*)?|999\.0*)$
```

- `^` - start of string (not sure if it's added by mod-security)
- `0*` - 0-n zeroes
- `(?:...)` - non-capturing group

  - `(?!...)` - if not followed by...

    - `999.\9` - the literal `999.9`,
    - `\d*` - 0-n digits and
    - `$` - the end of string
  - `\d` - digit
  - `{0,3}` - zero to three times
  - `(?:...)` - non-capturing group

    - `\.` - literal `.`
    - `\d*` - 0-n digits
  - `?` - optional
  - `|` - or
  - `999\.9` - `999.9` itself
  - `0*` - optional zeroes
- `$` - the end of string

Answer (score 1):

```
(^0\.0?[1-9]\d*|^[1-9]{1,3}\.\d+)
```

The first match alternative matches wanted numbers smaller one, the second if one or larger but smaller than one thousand. Does not match numbers not containing a dot, and does match numbers like 999.999, but only if smaller than one thousand (that's what you need I guess).